# Visual Studio 2017 - No IntelliSense for C++ template files

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I'm fairly new to C++, and I'm encountering some strange IntelliSense behavior from  Visual Studio when writing a template class. I have a separate header file and source file, with the source file being included in the header like so:

```
// header.h
#ifndef MY_HEADER 
#define MY_HEADER

namespace my_namespace {
    template <class Item>
    Item my_func(Item& item);
}

#include "template.template"
#endif

// template.template
namespace my_namespace {
    template <class Item>
    Item my_func(Item& item) {
        return item;
    }
}
```

It seems no matter what I do, IntelliSense doesn't work in `template.template` (I don't get the red squiggly underlines when missing a semi colon, etc). I have setup my custom .template extension already so that code highlighting works for my .template files, its specifically the red squiggles that are missing.

Stuff I've tried that doesn't work:

- I've made sure "Disable Squiggles" and "Disable Intellisense" are both set to False in "C/C++ -> Advanced" as other answers have suggested
- I've tried fully resetting/reloading my settings using the "Import and Export Settings" menu.
- In the file properties menu, I've tried excluding from build, not excluding from build, changing the Item type, etc.
- I've changed the extension .template to .cxx and .cpp
- Deleting the project .db file

How do I get my squiggles?

Comment: I've seen the project database get goofed. Try to close the project, delete the _.db in the project folder. When you open the project back up, the .db file will be rebuilt. Worth a try.

Comment: Try Right click on `template.template` file in Solution explorer -> Properties -> General -> Item type -> C/C++ header. Also I've never seen .template extension being used, probably `.inl` would be more common.

Comment: C++ template implementation files are somewhat out of context, since they are used to be included from template headers, thus the intellisense code parser has a hard time to putt all the stuff mentioned there into a reasonable context for mentioned symbols. Visual Studio isn't the only IDE that has problems to do that correctly.

Comment: @VTT That's at least a partial answer.

Comment: @lakeweb, just tried your suggestion, no luck.

Comment: @VTT, just tried your suggestion as well, again no luck.

Comment: Is `header.h` actually included in any translation unit?

Comment: @VTT, I'm honestly not sure what a translation unit is. The header is just included in my main file, and thats it. Its a super simple program.

Comment: @RobbyAllsopp A _translation unit_ refers to a specific c++ source file containing the final code definitions for all the (previously) introduced declarations.